# Scroll infinito não atualiza com classe CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css

#### Objetivo

Tenho uma tabela populada pelo banco de dados, e gostaria de atualizar conforme scroll for terminando.

---

#### Cenário teste

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#regs").scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() == $(this).get(0).scrollHeight) {
      //requisição ajax
      $("#regs").append($("#regsadd").html());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.registros {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="regs" class="registros">

  <table >
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div id="regsadd" hidden>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

---

#### Problema

- Não estão sendo aplicadas os estilos.

---

#### Dúvidas

- Como poderia resolver esse caso de forma mais simples possível?
- Quais outras formas?

Comment: acho que a forma mais simples é um plugin que já faça isso.. eu já vi esse funcionando e atende bem: https://github.com/anjlab/jquery-infinite-scroll

Comment: Você não está "apendando seus registros na tabela, por isso o css não é aplicado" Você está "apendando" na div regs

Comment: Outro erro. sua div "regsadd" tem as tags tr e td mas vai dar erro por não ter a tag table e se olhar o source no navegador vai ver que está apendando apenas texto puro.

Comment: Downvoters, poderiam explicar o motivo? Qual a dúvida? Ou também nem isso saberiam dizer? É muita infantilidade aqui cara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue correção do seu código funcionando (testado no Firefox 67.0.4)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#regs").scroll(function() {

   if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() ==  $(this).get(0).scrollHeight) {
     //requisição ajax
         debugger;
      $("#myTable tbody").append( $("#regsadd")[0].firstElementChild.firstElementChild.innerHTML  );

   };
  });
});
```

```css
.registros {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="regs" class="registros">

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div id="regsadd" hidden>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>  
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Elizeu, mas para facilitar, usei `$("#tabela tbody").append($("#regsadd > table > tbody").html());` para pegar o conteúdo de `tbody` da tabela a ser adicionada.

Comment: Eu também vou precisar fazer uma solução desta no meu trabalho em breve. Mas é bom testar em outros navegadores e fazer as adaptações necessárias (caso opte por não usar algum framework pronto, como vai ser meu caso)

Answer (score 2):

O seu `.append($("#regsadd").html());` está capturando somente o texto do conteúdo porque as tags de tabela não estão dentro de uma tabela. Adicionado a tag `<table>` no conteúdo, agora é possível capturar os elementos internos pelo `.html()`. Um outro problema é quando o conteúdo é colocado na nova tabela, você estava utilizando o ID *regs* na `<div` e não na tabela, então quando o conteúdo era adicionado ele ia pra dentro da `div`e não da tabela em si. Separando os ID's pra cada elemento, o ID da `div` possui apenas o propósito de adicionar o efeito **scroll** enquanto o ID da tabela, manipular seu conteúdo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tablescroll").scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() == $(this).get(0).scrollHeight) {
      //requisição ajax
      $("#regs").append($('#regsadd > table').html());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.registros {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tablescroll" class="registros">
  <table id="regs">
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div id="regsadd" hidden>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Douglas, o seu está dobrando os `tbody`.